# VS Code keyboard layout change

Tags: keyboard, visual-studio-code, keyboard-layout

I am using Visual Studio Code with English keyboard layout switched in Windows when programming, but when I am using my computer for general use I use Slovak keyboard layout. Sometimes it can get ridiculous when I switch from one to another multiple times in one minute. Is there a setting (or a plugin) that could set the keyboard layout in VS Code to English while Windows layout is still set to Slovak?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem so far?

Comment: I stopped searching, gave up on slovak keyboard layout.

Answer (score -1):

I will summarize for you the solution to this, hope it is still helpful for you or any other looking for this answer:

1. you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. then in the display that will appear at the top, write the language you want in case it does not appear
3. once this is done, VSC will ask you to restart.
4. once restarted is done it should be fine.

It is the way to do it without changing windows configuration as you will see in ther similar posts.
Hope it helps